# Calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix below, and I need to find the eigenvalues.\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -1 & 0 \\
        5 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
This is what I have done so far:
I used $\det(A-λI)=0$ and reached this form \begin{bmatrix}
        2-λ & -1 & 0 \\
        5 & 2-λ & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & 2-λ \\
       \end{bmatrix}
I have done some simplifications:

$(2-λ)[(2-λ)(2-λ)-4]-5(-(2-λ))=0$

$(2-λ)[(2-λ)(2-λ)-4]-5(-1)=0$

$(2-λ)[4-4λ+λ^2-4+5]=0$

$(2-λ)[λ^2-4λ+5]=0$

$λ^2(2-λ)-4λ(2-λ)+5(2-λ)=0$

$2λ^2-λ^3-8λ+4λ^2+10-5λ=0$

$-λ^3+6λ^2-13λ+10=0$

or $-λ(λ^2-6λ+13)+10=0$

$-λ (λ-(3+{\sqrt 22})) (λ+(3-{\sqrt 22}))+10=0$

Am I doing it right and if so:

I checked the answer on [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-eigenvalues-calculator/eigenvalues%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D2%26-1%260%5C%5C%205%262%264%5C%5C%200%261%262%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D) and it was $2,2-i,2+i$, How so? and what 
is $i$?

And is the matrix will be like this when I want to calculate the eigenvector for $2-i$ ??\begin{matrix}
        i & -1 & 0 \\
        5 & i & 4 \\
        0 & 1 & i \\
       \end{matrix}

Comment: When you have $(2-λ)[λ^2-4λ+5]=0$, you shouldn't expand. it is equivalent to solve $2-λ=0$ and $λ^2-4λ+5=0$. This would give you the good roots.

Comment: @Hamza The question "What is $i$?" is a little concerning. Before you hit the topic of eigenvalues, I would assume you have seen complex numbers at least once in some previous math course?

Comment: @imranfat I have seen a lot of complex numbers, but i just wanted to make sure that i don't missing something.

Comment: The answer to your last question is yes, too.  You need to row-reduce that, but using complex numbers.  So to eliminate the $5$, multiply the top row by $-5i$ and add to the second row.

Comment: One thing to point out (may or may not be relevant), electrical engineering uses $i$ for current, and instead use $j$ for complex numbers instead of $i$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can stop at the step $$(2-\lambda)(\lambda^2-4\lambda + 5) = 0.$$

Here you get the roots $\lambda = 2$ or $\lambda = 2 \pm i$.

Answer (score 4):

It happens that, if $\lambda=2$, then $-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-13\lambda+10=0$. In fact, $-\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-13\lambda+10=(2-\lambda)(\lambda^2-4\lambda+5)$. The roots of the polynomial $\lambda^2-4\lambda+5$ are [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) non-real numbers: $2+i$ and $2-i$.